# How to achieve mouseleave effect with absolutely-positioned non-descendants?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseleave, mouseout

One problem with the standard `mouseout` event is that it fires not only when the cursor leaves the region of the screen bounded by the element's external perimeter, but also when the cursor hovers over some other element contained within this perimeter.

The rationale for jQuery's `mouseleave` event is to signal *only* the moment when the cursor leaves the the area bounded by an element's external perimeter.

Unfortunately, this seems to work only if the "obstructing" element is a descendant of the "obstructed" element.  If the "obstructing" element is where it is through absolute positioning, then when the mouse hovers over it, the `mouseleave` event on the "obstructed" element gets fired.

For example, with the following HTML:

```
<div id="b-div">
    <div id="d-div"><span>d</span></div>
</div>
<div id="c-div"><span>c</span></div>
```

...`#d-div` is a bona-fide descendant of `#b-div`, whereas `#c-div` isn't, but, but we can style it so that it "obstructs" `#b-div` all the same.  This is illustrated in [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/p5yf0dcs/) jsFiddle.

If now one defines the following events on `#b-div`:

```
$( '#b-div' ).bind( {
    mouseenter: function () {
        $( this ).addClass( 'outlined' );
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $( this ).removeClass( 'outlined' );
    }
} );
```

...then hovering the mouse within `#b-div`'s outer perimeter causes a blue outline to appear over this perimeter, *unless* the mouse is over `#c-div`.

Is there a way to get the same effect with `#b-div` and `#c-div` as `mouseleave` achieves with `#b-div` and `#d-div`?

EDIT: I've fixed the example shown in the jsFiddle.  The original version of this example showed the unrepresentative special case in which all of the obstructing element overlaps with the obstructed element.  In this special case, the desired effect can be *simulated* by defining the same events on both the obstructing and the obstructed elements, thus, in effect, turning the obstructing element into a patch of the obstructed element.  This won't work when the obstructing element is not fully contained within the obstructed element's outer perimeter (as shown in the amended jsFiddle).  More generally, any solution that is based on using a `mouseover` event on the obstructing element is bound to fail, since the *real* problem is to prevent (or render ineffective) the spurious `mouseleave` on the obstructed element.

Comment: You mean like this -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/q1Lgzr4c/1/**

Comment: @adeneo: it turns out that my original example illustrated a somewhat unrepresentative special case; I've updated the example to correct this.  Sorry about that.

Comment: What almost works is checking the `e.relatedTarget` https://jsfiddle.net/p5yf0dcs/2/ The problem is that you now won't lose the highlight when mousing out of the `b-div`

Comment: Not sure I get it, wouldn't that still be trivial -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p5yf0dcs/4/**

Comment: @adeneo, I think kjo doesn't want `#b-div` to get the class *unless* it's under the mouse.  In your example, it gets the class when you mouse over any part of `#c-div`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does it, based on your initial post in which `#c-div` was completely contained within `#b-div`:

```
$('#b-div, #c-div').on( {
  mouseenter: function (ev) {
    $('#b-div').addClass('outlined');
  },
  mouseleave: function (ev) {
    $('#b-div').removeClass('outlined');
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/gorg2jgz/1)

---

Since `#c-div` may not always be contained completely within `#b-div`, you can use your existing code if you add this style:

```
#c-div {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

But this will make it impossible to interact with `#c-div` using the mouse.

[**Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/95v3mv1n/)

---

If you *do* need to interact with `#c-div`, *and* it's not completely within `#b-div`, you can use [**Element.getBoundingClientRect**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) like this:

```
$('#b-div, #c-div').on('mousemove mouseleave',
  function(ev) {
    var br= $('#b-div')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    $('#b-div').toggleClass(
      'outlined',
      ev.pageX > br.left && ev.pageX < br.left+br.width &&
      ev.pageY > br.top  && ev.pageY < br.top +br.height
    )
  }
);
```

[**Fiddle 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/bpwL4do6/2)

Comment: Upon seeing your solution I realized that my original example was
seriously flawed.  I have fixed it now.  I trust that with the
new version it will be clearer why solutions like the one you
proposed won't work in general (hovering over the parts of the
obstructing element that do not overlap with the obstructing
element should not trigger the `mouseenter` event).  I apologize
for the lack of clarity in my original post.

Comment: You could add `pointer-events: none` to the `#c-div` style – *unless* it has content that you need to interact with using the mouse.

Comment: @kjo do you still need an answer or you have found the issue resolution

Comment: @RickHitchcock: that idea works great.  I'd be happy to accept if you post it.

Comment: @MaxZoom: the solution in Rick Hitchcock's latest comment works very well, but if you have another solution, by all means, please post it.

Comment: Updated.   If you *do* need to interact with `#c-div`, you could use `getBoundingClientRect` to make sure mouse coordinates are within `#b-div`'s boundaries.

Comment: @RitchHItchcock [There's an easier way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30583154/227299)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use Rich's suggestions of `pointer-events: none` (maybe you need to [support IE 10](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) or you do need to interact with the absolutely positioned div), you can manually check that the event is not going to `#c-div` using [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/relatedTarget).

However, you also have to check that the mouseleave from `#c-div` is not going to `#b-div`.

```js
$( '#b-div' ).bind( {
    mouseenter: function () {
        $( this ).addClass( 'outlined' );
    },
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        if (e.relatedTarget.id == 'c-div' ||  $.contains(document.getElementById('c-div'), e.relatedTarget)) {
            return;
        }
        $( this ).removeClass( 'outlined' );
    }
} );

$( '#c-div' ).bind( {
    mouseleave: function (e) {
        if (e.relatedTarget.id == 'b-div' ||  $.contains(document.getElementById('b-div'), e.relatedTarget)) {
            return;
        }
        $( '#b-div' ).removeClass( 'outlined' );
    }
});
```

```css
#a-div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
}
#b-div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 50px;
}
#c-div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    background-color: #999;
}
#d-div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}
#c-div span {
    margin: 21.5px;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#d-div span {
    margin: auto;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.outlined {
    outline: 10px solid steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a-div">
    <div id="b-div"><div id="d-div"><span>d</span></div></div>
    <div id="c-div"><span>c</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't highlight `#b-div` if you initially hover `#c-div`, so I don't think it completely meets the OP's requirements.